# Как без кнопки button запустить событие onClick?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Всем добра ! Задача -такого плана, имеется java Fragment я использую его, как переопределяющий. В нем есть кнопка button. Желательно как то указать обработчику void onClick, что кнопка уже нажата, сразу, при запуске этого Fragment_а. Что бы не открывалось окно с кнопкой.
Вот текст фрагмента:

```
public class PromFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener { 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper2, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttun);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Glass.class);
         getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы явно делаете что-то неправильно. Зачем вашей кнопке знать, что она кликнута если она не кликнута пользователем???

Если вам нужно запустить какое-то событие при открытии нового экрана, то так и делайте. Создавайте метод, который вам нужно вызвать и вызывайте его в одном из методов Жизненного цикла, например `onStart()`.

Comment: дело в том, что фрагмент открывается из enum в Activity. В enum -10 case и все вызывают фрагмент. Но в одном case, мне надо, что бы открывался не Fragment , а Activity. поэтому этот фрагмент, как промежуточный. И кнопка типа "подтвердить" ни к чему. Попробую познакомиться с onStart()  спасибо !

Comment: Значит передавайте какой-то флаг в ваш фрагмент по которому будет смотреть нужно ли открыть новый фрагмент сразу, или вообще решайте вопрос открытия нужного фрагмента до его открытия. То, что хотите сделать вы это дикий костыль. Вы еще и жизнь сами себе усложняете.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно переходить по программно без нажатия кнопки. Поэтому я бы предложил переместить данный код:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Glass.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

в отдельный метод:

```
void moveNext(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Glass.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
}
```

и дальше в обработчик кнопки пишем вызов данного метода. И дальше как вам указали из опережающего мой ответ ответа вставьте вызов метода в методы ЖЦ.